# Fixed Floating Element Stop at Footer

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, footer, css-position

I've used the code from http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements to float an element after scrolling to a certain point. Here is the site I'm working on: http://bodyecology.com/articles/gut-type-update

As you can see, the right column becomes fixed when scrolled, but overlaps at the footer. How can I cause it to stop at just above the footer?

Currently Using:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {  
    var top = jQuery('#news_sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat(jQuery('#news_sidebar').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
    jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {

        var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

        if (y >= top) {

        jQuery('#news_sidebar').addClass('fixed');

        } else {

       jQuery('#news_sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This fiddle does what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/9/

Here is the javascript that handles the floating element $('#summary') on the right:

```
$('#summary').scrollToFixed({
    marginTop:
        $('.header').outerHeight() + 10,
    limit:
        $('.footer').offset().top -
        $('#summary').outerHeight() -
        10
});
```

Here is the jquery plugin and its source:

https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

Comment: @bigspotteddog I'm embarrassed to so shamelessly hijack this comment thread, but I couldn't figure out another way to privately message you. I'm struggling to use your plugin scrolltofixed correctly. If you would take a quick look at [this stackoverflow question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987447/scroll-multiple-sidebar-divs-down-the-screen-like-9gag-com-does/10989465) I will be eternally grateful.

Comment: @billmalarky I have responded to your shamelessly hijacked comment :) on the question you linked above.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same code as you to float my div
from the same post "Fixing-Floating-Elements"

and had the same problem as you have with the overlapping footer, the ONLY solution working for me (i'm a javascript newvie) was pulling the div away from the footer with this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

            // distance from top of footer to top of document
            footertotop = ($('#footer').position().top);
            // distance user has scrolled from top, adjusted to take in height of sidebar (570 pixels inc. padding)
            scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop() + 570;
            // difference between the two
            difference = scrolltop - footertotop;

            // if user has scrolled further than footer,
            // pull sidebar up using a negative margin

            if (scrolltop > footertotop) {

                $('#cart').css('margin-top', 0 - difference);
            }

            else {
                $('#cart').css('margin-top', 0);
            }


        });
```

This was helpful to me i hope someone else will find it helpful :)
I've implemented it on my site so the users can get [full articles view](http://www.mentallica.co.il/overview)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it appears to be the size of the content inside the right sidebar. It overlaps because its too big not to when you scroll to the bottom.

You could put the same stop and re-position at the bottom as you do on top. When you scroll to the top, it re-positions itself. Try that for the footer as well.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it so that it's not so big. Imagine your viewport is much smaller, and the element would overlap the footer. I'd like to make it bigger but get it to stop before the footer. What would I add to the script to stop it at the footer?

Comment: I've added this page as an example of what I'd like to do: http://bodyecology.com/example.html. Notice that the element is longer now, so it overlaps the footer.