# scroll multiple sidebar divs down the screen like 9gag.com does

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

Stack,

Basically, I want a homepage with multiple posts stacked on top of each other like techcrunch or basically any blog. With each post, I'd like to have a sidebar box that floats down the page next to the post as you scroll so the user can easily share the post via a facebook like button or whatever without having to scroll back up to the top of the post.

When the person gets to the bottom of each post, the sidebar stops floating down the screen, and when the peson keeps scrolling to the next post, the next post's sidebar begins to float down and so on.

A perfect example is the 9gag.com homepage. Notice how the post title, favorite button, and social buttons, float next to each post/picture.

I'm trying to use jquery's scrolltofixed plugin to accomplish this, but I'm getting stuck. I can get the sidebar divs to begin scrolling down the page correctly, but I can't get them to stop scrolling when you get to the bottom of each post so they just begin to overlap on each other.

Typically, you would stop them from scrolling using the "limit" attribute that is built into scrolltofixed like so:

```
$('.class-of-sidebar-box-div').scrollToFixed({
limit: 3000
});
```

This would stop the sidebar box from scrolling with the screen once you've scrolled down 3000 pixels.

What I tried to do, was dynamically set the limit to the height of each accompanying post + the top offset of the accompanying post - the height of the sidebar box in order to stop each sidebar box from scrolling when it got to the bottom of the accompanying post.

Example code:

```
$('.class-of-sidebar-box-div').scrollToFixed({
limit: function(){
    var postoffset = $(this).siblings('.accompanying-post-class').offset().top;
    var postheight = $(this).siblings('.accompanying-post-class').height();
    var sidbardivheight = $(this).height();
    var scrolllimit = postoffset + postheight - sidbardivheight ;
    return scrolllimit;
    }
});
```

This is failing. The sidebar boxes start floating correctly, but the "limit" is not being set correctly.

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

UPDATE: Fixed example code as suggested by Brilliand. However, the limit is still not being set. Additionally, I tried a simpler function as follows and even it didn't work.

Simpler example that also failed:

```
$('.class-of-sidebar-box-div').scrollToFixed({
limit: function(){
    var scrolllimit = 1000;
    return scrolllimit;
    }
});
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3qV5/760/.

It is using the scrolltofixed plugin you mentioned above: https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

Unfortunately, the limit option does not take a function at this time.  Great idea though and the next version should have that.

**EDIT: the latest version of the plugin now supports "limit" as a function as well as a value.**

What I have done to get a similar effect to what you have described above is to set the limit to the offset().top of the next section minus the sidebar height plus some padding, just as you described above.  Knowing that the limit option will not accept a function will help with the confusion:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cart1').scrollToFixed({
        marginTop: 10,
        limit: $('#p2').offset().top - $('#cart1').height() - 10
    });
    $('#cart2').scrollToFixed({
        marginTop: 10,
        limit: $('#p3').offset().top - $('#cart2').height()
    });
});
```

And, here is a way to iterate over the carts to set them next to their respective divs as you mentioned in your comment below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (i = 1; i <= $('.cart').length; i++) {
        $('#cart' + i).scrollToFixed({
            marginTop: 10,
            limit: $('#p' + (i + 1)).offset().top - $('#cart' + i).height() - 10
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Make sure you pay attention to the css as well.  At the very bottom of the css is where the carts are placed next to their respective sections using floats.

Comment: Clever workaround, it will add a lot of code since I've got 20 divs that need it applied, but it may be a good solution until you decide to add the function feature to scrolltofixed. I also wanted to add a big thank you for taking the time to respond (and even including a solution as opposed to just saying scrolltofixed doesn't support the functionality I was looking for). I set your answer as the accepted answer since it brought full closure to the question. Thanks again bigspotteddog!

Comment: @billmalarky Here is the updated fiddle that eliminates the duplicated code for the 20 divs you mentioned.  It iterates through the $('.carts') and sets their marginTops and limits: http://jsfiddle.net/y3qV5/768/

Comment: @billmalarky I had a slight issue with the for loop.  Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3qV5/769/

Answer (score 0):

`.scrollTop()` is the wrong function - it will increase as the user scrolls down, preventing the limit from ever actually being reached.  Looking at the scrollToTop documentation, I think what you want is `$(this).siblings('.accompanying-post-class').offset().top`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. However, I can't get this plugin to handle functions in the options at all. I've tried `$('.class-of-sidebar-box-div').scrollToFixed({limit: function(){var scrolllimit = 1000;return scrolllimit;}});` and I can't even get something as simple as that to work. I don't get it, because in the documentation found here: https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed, the "Very Full Example" suggest this should work.

Comment: I don't see anything there suggesting that the `limit` parameter accepts a function.  But you may not need it - the bottom of the post div will move seldom, if at all.  You can probably get away with calculating the value once, and providing that value as the `limit` parameter directly.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to jquery/javascript, so I assumed all plugin parameters could accept functions. In the plugin example they set limit like this `limit: $('.footer').offset().top - $('#summary').outerHeight() - 10`. I've tried something like this to no avail `$('.class-of-sidebar-box-div').scrollToFixed({limit:$(this).siblings('.accompanying-post-class').offset().top+$(this).siblings('.accompanying-post-class').height()-$(this).height()});`. Thoughts?

Comment: "the bottom of the post div will move seldom, if at all. You can probably get away with calculating the value once, and providing that value as the limit parameter directly." I believe this would work. But how would I calculate it dynamically for each post?

Comment: You'd need to use each() and call scrollToFixed() on each element in a loop, rather than calling it on all of them simultaneously.  That way you can provide a slightly different parameter object for each one.